# Linq groupby in aspnet core 3.1 can not process LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have this linq query:

```
var x= _context.Bollature
            .Where(b => b.DataOra >= from.Value && b.DataOra <= to && (b.UtenteId == utenteId || utenteId == null))
            .GroupBy(g => new { g.UtenteId, g.DataOra.Date })
            .OrderBy(o => o.Key.Date)
            .Select(e => new { e.Key.UtenteId, DataRiferimento = e.Key.Date, HasError = (e.Count() % 2) != 0})
            .ToList();
```

And work fine, but if add the list of object on projecion like this:

```
var x= _context.Bollature
            .Where(b => b.DataOra >= from.Value && b.DataOra <= to && (b.UtenteId == utenteId || utenteId == null))
            .GroupBy(g => new { g.UtenteId, g.DataOra.Date })
            .OrderBy(o => o.Key.Date)
            .Select(e => new { e.Key.UtenteId, DataRiferimento = e.Key.Date, HasError = (e.Count() % 2) != 0, Bollature=e })
            .ToList();
```

show this message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Processing of the LINQ expression
> '(GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: new {
> UtenteId = (b.UtenteId),
> Date = (CONVERT((b.DataOra), (date)))  },  ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: BollaturaEntity
> ValueBufferExpression:
> (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
> IsNullable: False ) )' by 'RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may
> indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed
> information.'

Can we help me?

Comment: I guess it's naming issue. Change the `Bollature=e` to `BollatureData=e` to verify it. If it works, then it might be a bug. If not, try to `ToList().Select(....)`.

Comment: GroupBy in EF core is full of this kind of issues. Please look for other questions in this area. There are too many to answer them all.

Comment: The fundamental issue is EF Core 3.1 `GroupBy` only implements translations that map directly to SQL `GROUP BY` which means you can only have references to the `Key` or aggregate functions in the `Select`. You could put `AsEnumerable` before the `GroupBy` to group on the client side, or emulate `GroupJoin` to send back the shape you want, but you must think about how you would return a single table from SQL (e.g. you can't have a hierarchical SQL return value).